# Detailed data about Medicare Enrollment?

Tags: data.gov

I found [CMS Medicare Enrollment Reports](https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/MedicareEnrpts/index.html?redirect=/medicareEnrpts/) broken down by different parts, regions... I'm wondering if there are more detailed open data sources from which these reports are generated?

For instance, I understand that about [10,000 baby-boomers per day](http://www.medpac.gov/documents/reports/chapter-2-the-next-generation-of-medicare-beneficiaries-(june-2015-report).pdf) are aging into Medicare. I'd like to know how many folks are first-time enrollees versus those who needed to go back and re-enroll (because of life qualifying events and such).